# Django - Do different queries depending on value of field

Tags: django

I'm stuck on a seemingly simple issue.  I want to do a different queryset if `sold_data` is empty.  Is there an effective way to do this?  Or do I need to use a for loop and loop over all the listing objects and check each one?

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    list_price = models.IntegerField()
    sold_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    ... other fields
```

---

```
data = Listing.objects.filter(...) # Note: I had already made other queries

if sold_price == None:
    data = data.filter(list_price__gte=1)
else:
    data = data.filter(sold_price__gte=1)
```

Comment: Do you mean "for each record, take it if the sold price is at least 1, or if there is no list price, then if sold price is at least 1"? Satendra is right. If you mean "If no records have sold price, filter on list price; but if even one row has sold price, then filter on sold price"? Then taoufix A is right.

Comment: Hey @Valachio, i was wondering that, did any of answers helped?

Comment: @Satendra I just checked my code today.  Your answer worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [**`Q object`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

```
from django.db.models import Q

# your filtered queryset is in 'data' varibale
data.filter(Q(sold_price__isnull=False, sold_price__gte=1) | Q(sold_price__isnull=True, list_price__gte=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna check if an object is None use the `is` operator
I'm not sure if I did understand your question here is what I get :  you wanna filter list_price if the data contains an object with empty value else filter sold_price

You can try this

```
if data.filter(sold_price__isnull=True).exists():
    data = data.filter(list_price__gte=1)
else:
    data = data.filter(sold_price__gte=1)
```